# MySQL -- transaction involving tables in 3 different databases?

Tags: mysql

In `MySQL`, I have three different databases -- let's call them `A`, `B` and `C`.

Is it possible to perform a transaction involving tables that are in all three databases (`A`, `B`, `C`)? (all databases are on the same server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. This is a demo query:

```
select (SELECT count(*) FROM `A`.`tableInA`),
       (SELECT count(*) FROM `B`.`tableInB`),
       (SELECT count(*) FROM `C`.`tableInC`);
```

---

Another demo query:

```
SELECT * FROM `A`.`tableInA` 
      where fieldInA in (SELECT fieldInAB FROM `B`.`tableInB` 
            where fieldInB in (select fieldInBC from `C`.`tableInC`));
```

Comment: @Harry Joy: thank you. you demonstrated a query using `SELECT`. My question was, is it possible to perform a `TRANSACTION` involving (say) 3 databases?

Comment: @user540009: yes you can. Try it and let me know.

Comment: @Harry Joy: thank you. In such a case, does it matter what engine is used for the tables (`MyISAM` / `InnoDB`)?

Comment: @user540009: all should be in same thing.

Comment: @Harry Joy: meaning, all tables that are involved in the transaction should be of the same engine (say, `InnoDB`)?